# not in in select query

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

```
select * from emp where job_type<>'ANALYST';
```

I have similar query in my project. I have been told to find other way to remove not equal to, because index is not used if you do so.

I have no other filter condition, can I do some work around to fool optimizer?

Comment: remaining record list is long, I mean if I include others in the in so it is huge

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*I have been told to find other way to remove not equal to,*

is generally bad advice. Queries should be written as per the function required.  That said, it *might* be the case that ANALYST occupies the vast majority of the data in your table, and thus you could do something like:

```
select * from emp where job_type < 'ANALYST' or job_type > 'ANALYST'
```

which could be transformed internally to a union all on the appropriate index by the optimizer.  Or if you *knew* in advance the list of distinct values, you could have something like

```
select * from emp where job_type in (...)
```

or if they were in a parent table, something like

```
select * from emp where job_type in 
  ( select job_type from valid_job_types here job_type != 'ANALYST' )
```

on the assumption that EMP is large and VALID_JOB_TYPES is small.

But I would push back and ask for a justification on the request, because using an index is not *always* the best thing to do

Comment: Aww....never thought there are so many ways to write one query. thank you so so much Connor.  Actually We have to fetch data for reporting tool. our backend requirement is still same. looking at timeline we have to deliver product. we are thinking for large changes in next release. performance team raised the above issue,so we are looking for work around

Comment: Actually cost of this query select * from emp where job_type < 'ANALYST' or job_type > 'ANALYST' and query I mentioned is coming same. total 150k record in the table and 37k belongs to Analyst

Comment: Which proves my point (ie, your performance team is wrong). To read 110k out of 150k records, a full table scan will almost *always* be the best option